# T-SQL Generate intervals from two dates

Tags: sql, t-sql

I want to generate intervals like this:

```
 - ID | START_INTERVAL
 - 1 | 12:00
 - 2 | 12:30
 - 3 | 13:00
 - 4 | 13:30
 - 5 | 16:00
 - 6 | 16:30
 - 7 | 17:00
 - 8 | 17:30
```

From this:

```
- ID | START | STOP | INTERVAL
 - 1 | 2018-05-03 12:00:00 | 2018-05-03 14:00:00 | 30
 - 2 | 2018-05-03 16:00:00 | 2018-05-03 18:00:00 | 30
```

It is possible to generate this from t-sql or i need to use PHP ?

Comment: Where from did you get `2018-05-03`? What if it will pass to next day? Can there be other intervals except 30?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL query to generate one hour time slots between the start TIme and end Time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49364966/sql-query-to-generate-one-hour-time-slots-between-the-start-time-and-end-time)

Comment: Why do you need to do this in T-SQL, not in server or client side? Because certainly this is more of algorithm rather than database thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, you want some kind of *recursive* `cte`

```
with cte as (
    select id, start, stop, interval from table t
    union all
    select id, dateadd(MINUTE, interval, start) start, stop, interval
    from cte c
    where start < stop
)
select id, start as start_interval from cte c
order by 1
```